# How to write unit test in an ASP.NET MVC 5 project?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, unity-container

I have a project that is written with c# on the top of ASP.NET MVC 5 framework. I set up an IoC using [Unity-container](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Dependency-Injection-in-11d54863) to handle dependency injections.

I need to write some test cases to help me test my project. I added a new project (Unit Test Project (.NET Framework)) to my solution for testing. In my first test class, I need to utilize my `Ioc` container to resolve dependencies.

I tried to do constructor injection for my test class, but I got an error stating that there was a parameterless constructor.

How can I correctly setup my test class to my dependencies are initialized from the `IoC` container and ready for testing?

Here is my first test class

```
[TestClass]
public class AnnouncerTests
{
    private static IAnnouncer Accouncer;

    [ClassInitialize]
    public static void SetUp(TestContext context)
    {
        // this does not work
        var container = UnityConfig.GetConfiguredContainer();

        Accouncer = new Announcer(container);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void Multiple_Events_Fire_When_Event_Rises()
    {
        var user = new User()
        {
            FirstName = "First Name Test",
            LastName = "Last Name Test"
        };

        Accouncer.Announce(new UserWasCreated(user));
        // Assert .....


    }
}
```

How can I resolve types from my IoC from inside a test class?

Comment: If you were to use the real objects, (which you presumably were going to do since you wanted to set up Unity) then you'd be testing multiple bits of your code at once. That defeats the purpose of a unit test. In a unit test, you should identify exactly which public method you want to test (known as System Under Test or SUT). Any external dependencies that has should be mocked, don't use your real implementations. This isolates your test so that you can tightly control what the external bits do for your test, so you can simulate expected and unexpected behavior to make sure the SUT works.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to use the container in your test. The container just needed for resolving dependencies in your application and there are no reasons to use it in tests.

For testing classes, you have to mock your dependencies. There are lots of libraries for mocking and creating test data: Moq, NSubstitute, Autofixture.

Post about how to use Moq for testing controller in mvc [here](https://deanhume.com/test-your-mvc-routes-with-moq/)